# ¿What is maxIter parameter in MultilayerPerceptronClassifier - Spark - mllib?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

**¿What is maxIter in MultilayerPerceptronClassifier - Spark - mllib?**

**1.** The parameter maxIter tells the optimization algorithm the maximum number of hops it is allowed to do to find the minimum error?

**OR**

**2.** The parameter maxIter tells the maximum number of epochs (the number maximum of times the entire dataset goes through the network)?

```
class pyspark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(featuresCol='features', labelCol='label', predictionCol='prediction', maxIter=100, tol=1e-06, seed=None, layers=None, blockSize=128, stepSize=0.03, solver='l-bfgs', initialWeights=None, probabilityCol='probability', rawPredictionCol='rawPrediction')
```

Comment: I have reviewed the source code of the MultilayerPerceptronClassifier class and have seen that the maxIter parameter is one of the gradient calculation stop criteria, and that blockSize is used in the spark mapPartitions method. Thanks a lot by your help @EmiCareOfCell44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark gradient optimizer works using RDD treeAggregate function. Each iteration it takes a fraction of the RDD, by default 1, and distributes the gradient optimization operation over the workers, it takes **the whole RDD each iteration**. In this case one iteration can be considered as one epoch. This approach simplifies the optimization process using Spark. There are another more advanced deep learning optimizer implementations, like BigDL, that allows to set the batch size and uses the BlockManager to compute the distributed gradient aggregation for each iteration. In that case, one iteration corresponds to one mini-batch execution.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala

```
  /**
   * Aggregates the elements of this RDD in a multi-level tree pattern.
   * This method is semantically identical to [[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD#aggregate]].
   *
   * @param depth suggested depth of the tree (default: 2)
   */
  def treeAggregate[U: ClassTag](zeroValue: U)(
      seqOp: (U, T) => U,
      combOp: (U, U) => U,
      depth: Int = 2): U = withScope {
    require(depth >= 1, s"Depth must be greater than or equal to 1 but got $depth.")
    if (partitions.length == 0) {
      Utils.clone(zeroValue, context.env.closureSerializer.newInstance())
    } else {
      val cleanSeqOp = context.clean(seqOp)
      val cleanCombOp = context.clean(combOp)
      val aggregatePartition =
        (it: Iterator[T]) => it.aggregate(zeroValue)(cleanSeqOp, cleanCombOp)
      var partiallyAggregated: RDD[U] = mapPartitions(it => Iterator(aggregatePartition(it)))
      var numPartitions = partiallyAggregated.partitions.length
      val scale = math.max(math.ceil(math.pow(numPartitions, 1.0 / depth)).toInt, 2)
      // If creating an extra level doesn't help reduce
      // the wall-clock time, we stop tree aggregation.

      // Don't trigger TreeAggregation when it doesn't save wall-clock time
      while (numPartitions > scale + math.ceil(numPartitions.toDouble / scale)) {
        numPartitions /= scale
        val curNumPartitions = numPartitions
        partiallyAggregated = partiallyAggregated.mapPartitionsWithIndex {
          (i, iter) => iter.map((i % curNumPartitions, _))
        }.foldByKey(zeroValue, new HashPartitioner(curNumPartitions))(cleanCombOp).values
      }
      val copiedZeroValue = Utils.clone(zeroValue, sc.env.closureSerializer.newInstance())
      partiallyAggregated.fold(copiedZeroValue)(cleanCombOp)
    }
  }
```